How to serialize my object which gives out the whole structure using newtonsoft json?
I am trying to print out a json structure of my object using newtonsoft. For eg:-
class details1{
 public string var1;
 public list<details2> list1;
}

class details2{
 public string var2;
 public list<details3> list2;
}

class details3{
 public string var3;
}

the output I require:
{
 "var1":"",
 "list1":
 [
  {
   "var2":"",
   "list2":
   [
     {
      "var3":""
     }
   ]
  }
 ]
}

The output I am getting:
{
 "var1":null,
 "list1":null
}

What am I doint wrong?
Tried using JsonConvert.Serialize and JsonSerializer both, but the same results.
I was able to get it to show an empty list of details1 i.e. list1 but not the contents of that list i.e. details2.
class details1{
 public details1(){
  list1=new List<details2>();
 }
 public string var1;
 public list<details2> list1;
}

output:
{
 "var1":null,
 "list1":[]
}


The purpose of the JSON is to describe the data, not the structure. If you want the entire structure reflected in the JSON, populate every attribute.

Behaves exactly as expected. Also: please show actual code. list<details> won't compile unless you defined a custom class list<T> ... I'd also recommend to follow C# naming conventions in C# code. You can define how those are mapped in json by various means ( Settings/Options, Attributes ... )

"but not the contents of that list" - it is correctly showing [], because the list is empty; it would be an error of the serializer to describe a non-empty collection when given an empty list; the serializer is doing exactly what it should do; if you want to show a list with one element: give it a list with one element

If you actually want to represent the structure of your classes it is called a schema, and see generating schemas for how to create one.

Json.NET (and all other JSON serializers) will generate JSON corresponding to the values you have actually constructed.  To get the JSON you show in your question you need to construct the equivalent c# class instances in memory first, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/XLKyXU.  If you are looking for a tool to generate "example" JSON from type definitions alone you need a different tool.  See e.g. How to generate JSON example values for class, just like Swagger does for example response?.  Does that question also answer yours?

it does not work as you want with lists... also please pay attantion on @dbc comment in question thread.
trying to show you on example:
void Main()
{
    var x = new first();
    //x.lst.AddRange(new List<thirdClass>(){ new thirdClass() {third1="xxx"}});
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings() {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include} ).Dump();
}

public class first { 
    public string first1 {get;set;}
    public string first2 {get;set;}
    public string first3 { get; set; }
    public secondClass second1 { get; set; }
    //[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default, PropertyName = "lst", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
    public List<thirdClass> lst {get;set;}
    public first() {second1 = new secondClass(); lst = new List<thirdClass>();}
}

public class secondClass{
    public string second1 { get; set; }
    public string second2 {get;set;}
    public thirdClass third2 {get;set;}
    public secondClass(){
        third2 = new thirdClass();
    }
}
public class thirdClass
{
    public string third1 {get;set;}
}


the result would be
{
  "first1": null,
  "first2": null,
  "first3": null,
  "second1": {
    "second1": null,
    "second2": null,
    "third2": {
      "third1": null
    }
  },
  "lst": []
}

if you uncomment second line - it will serialize list object
{
  "first1": null,
  "first2": null,
  "first3": null,
  "second1": {
    "second1": null,
    "second2": null,
    "third2": {
      "third1": null
    }
  },
  "lst": [
    {
      "third1": "xxx"
    }
  ]
}

Also, you can call NJsonSchema (nuget) that what i tried
NJsonSchema.JsonSchema.FromType(typeof(first)).ToSampleJson().ToString()

and it might populate what you expect..
with your classes, (its weird but kind of worked for me)

all variables and class names must be Camel Casing

should be properties (not fields)

and schema got created for first incursion (weird)


{
  "var1": "var1",
  "list1": [
    {
      "var2": "var2"
    }
  ]
}

another try i did as Newtonsoft Schema Generator - which created correct schema
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
    //generator.SchemaIdGenerationHandling = SchemaIdGenerationHandling.TypeName;
    //generator.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    //generator.GenerationProviders.Add(new StringEnumGenerationProvider());
    generator.Generate(typeof(Details1)).ToString().Dump();

--
{
  "definitions": {
    "Details2": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Var2": {
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        },
        "List2": {
          "type": [
            "array",
            "null"
          ],
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Details3"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Var2",
        "List2"
      ]
    },
    "Details3": {
      "type": [
        "object",
        "null"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Var3": {
          "type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "Var3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Var1": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "List1": {
      "type": [
        "array",
        "null"
      ],
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Details2"
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Var1",
    "List1"
  ]
}

